# Infinite qudit to solve halting problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

My understanding of qudits and quantum computing isn't exactly the best, but as far as I know, a qudit is defined as a superposition of D states. Reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02896), as best I could tell, a qudit such that D is infinite is possible. Following that, would it be theoretically possible to represent each possibility as a seperate infinite qudit, where that qudit would store, say, the result of the Collatz conjecture of a number. From there, could you then do something such that all numbers that end in the 4-2-1 loop destructively interfere with each other and you are only left with numbers that do not end in a 4-2-1 loop; if there is anything left, it means that there is a number that doesn't end in the 4-2-1 loop, and if there isn't, then every number ends in the 4-2-1 loop.

Additionally, would it be possible to determine whether a qudit is infinite or not?